# Proper way to render a series of HTML tags with the "for in" loop in React

Tags: reactjs

Here's a condensed version of my code.  I think you can get what I'm trying to do, but only the first name displays.  Can anyone show me the proper way to do this in React?

```
  import "./styles.css";
  import { useState } from "react"; 



  export default function App() {
  const [annie, renameAnnie] = useState({
    firstname: "Annie",
    middlename: "Rose",
    lastname: "Markham"
  });

  const fullName = () => {
    for (let x in annie) {
      return(
     <span>{annie[x]}</span>
      )
    }
  };


  return (
    <>
      {fullName()}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because the single `<span>` will be returned on the first iteration. Instead, try

```
    return (
        <>
            {Object.values(annie).map((item, index) => (
                <span key={index}>{item}</span>
            ))}
        </>
    )
```

Essentially, using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) we can construct a new array where each element is yielded by a function on the values of `annie`. You can think of it as a more concise way to write the following:

```js
const results = []
const values = Object.values(annie)
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    results.append(<span key={i}>{values[i]}</span>)
}
return <>{results}</>
```

Answer (score 1):

> but only the first name displays

This is because of the `return` statement inside the `for` loop.

an alternative is to make the `fullName` function returning an array of `span` from the `annie` object using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), then this can be displayed within the JSX :

```js
const fullName = () => {
    return Object.values(annie).map((value, index) => (
      <span key={index}>{value}</span>
    ));
  };
```